# How to repeat question if user input is invalid

Tags: python

I want to repeat the question "invalid option" but i dont know how ive tried using while loop.

this is what i have so far

```
def path_1():# define path 1 option from user input
  bats = input("You chose path 1, you continue your journy in path 1 its a cave. just you and your dog. its dark. the only light source you have is your dim torch. you hear a peculiar noise it sounds like screechin as it comes closer you realize its a flock of hungry blood sucking bats with gren eyes and purple skin you have no weapons you have two options to run or sacrifice your dog(run or sacrifice?)")
  if bats == "run":
    print("you ran but didnt get far. the bats sucked all your blood and you died GAME OVER")
    decrease_health()

  elif bats == "sacrifice":
    print("you sadly had to grab a rock and smash your dogs head so it can bleed the bats targeted your dog and you made a run for it while hearing your dog squel for help as you pass by him :(   ")
  else:
    print("Invalid option, options were sacrifice or run try again")
    path_1()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in a loop, without recursion?

Comment: You say you've tried using a while loop, but there is no `while` in this code.  Your question should always include the thing you tried and an explanation of exactly how it didn't work.  That way the answer can sometimes be as simple as pointing out one small thing that got missed.